# Websocket, rtk query и api binance. Проблема с запросом

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, binance

Я хочу получить основную информацию по бирже запросом: [wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/exchangeInfo](https://wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/exchangeInfo). Я так же использую rtk query. **Проблема в том, что данные почему то не приходят**. Код до console.log(data) даже не доходит.
Это само место запроса:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const CoinApi=createApi({
    reducerPath: 'coinApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl:'/'}),
    endpoints: (build)=>({
        getCoin: build.query<any,void>({
            query:()=>`/ws/exchangeInfo`,
            async onCacheEntryAdded(
                arg,
                { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }
              ) {
                const ws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/exchangeInfo')
                try {
                    await cacheDataLoaded
                    const listener = (event: MessageEvent) => {
                      const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
                      updateCachedData((draft) => {
                        draft.push(data)
                      })
                      console.log(data)
                    }
                    ws.addEventListener('message', listener)
                } catch {
                    console.log('error')
                }
                await cacheEntryRemoved
                ws.close()
              },
        })
    })
})
export const {useGetCoinQuery}=CoinApi
```

Это место, где я использую хук useGetCoinQuery

```
const CoinName = () => {
      const {data, isLoading, isError, isFetching, isSuccess}=useGetCoinQuery()
        const coin='Coin name'
        const [isActiveModal, setIsActiveModal]=useState<boolean>(false)
        const copyText=()=>{
          navigator.clipboard.writeText(coin)
          setIsActiveModal(true)
          setTimeout(()=>{
            setIsActiveModal(false)
          }, 1000)
        }
      return (
        <div className={styles.wrap}>
            <h1>{coin} <ContentCopyIcon onClick={copyText}/></h1>
            <ModalCopied isActiveModal={isActiveModal}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Может проблема в base url? если я его меняю на wss://stream.binance.com:9443. то показывает ошибку: Fetch API cannot load wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/exchangeInfo. URL scheme "wss" is not supported.